# Merging Subversion Branches

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Just asking a simple question. 
What is the best way to merge two Subversion branches together?

I wish to merge branch name `3661` into branch name `2011-01-17`

`3661` has a revision code of `16658`

`2011-01-17` has a revision code of `16613`

Comment: The only important revision number is the revision where the branch was created: is that what you mean by revision code?

Comment: revision code is the commit revision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I do (I use command line)

(1) Get the revision of `3661` when the branch was created like this

```
svn log --verbose --stop-on-copy http://url/to/branch/3661
```

Take the smallest revision from the output. Let's say it's 911

(2) Checkout the latest of branch `2011-01-17`, and run this in the main directory. This will show all the conflicts and updates but won't do anything.

```
 svn merge --dry-run -r 911:HEAD http://url/to/branch/3661
```

(3) If you are OK with the changes do a actual merge

```
 svn merge -r 911:HEAD http://url/to/branch/3661
```

Nothing is committed on server yet. It's just you local copy is merged. You may want to fix all the conflicted file now.

(4) If you want to persist the merge on server commit the changed files by doing this

```
 svn commit -m "Merged 3661 changes into 2011-01-17"
```

Hopefully this helps. You may want to see this chapter of red book http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s04.html

Also, you need command line SVN client. You can download it from Subversion's website

Comment: One GOTCHA.  If you ever did a Tortoise "rename" on branch "3661", then the --stop-on-copy will only go back to this.  Since rename (in tortoise) in actually a copy and delete I think.  I learned this the hard way. :<